# Read all of Lucifer's story from his spin off on Sandman?

Tags: suggested-order, the-sandman, lucifer

I would like to read Lucifer's story from the very beginning which I know started in a Sandman comic book issue. Which are the Sandman comics that involve Lucifer and after that do I read the books?? A little guidance would be helpful

Comment: There are many mentions of Lucifer in Sandman. However, his origin story is only told briefly.

Comment: I just noticed there are additional Lucifer comics. I'll read them and update my answer.

Comment: I simply want to have the whole story from its beginning before the solo Lucifer series and I am kinda confused, can you send me links for those volumes you mentioned as to where I can buy them ? and thanks for all he info

Comment: Updated my answer with the list of works. Ideally, you should read them in this order, but I doubt you'll get spoilers or confusions if you read them in other order. As to where you can buy them, I'd recommend the usual: comic shops, Amazon, DC's own website, etc. Since those are older comics, you'll probably find it easier to purchase them online in digital form.

Comment: There is a list of collected editions [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lucifer_(DC_Comics)), but it doesn't include Lucifer's appearances in *Sandman*.

Answer (score 3):

**TL;DR**: Read *Sandman* volume 1, 3, 9; *Sandman Presents: Lucifer* #1-#3, *Lucifer: Nirvana* (one-shot) and the *Lucifer* series by Mike Carey (75 issues) - preferably in this order.

*The Sandman* volumes are important because they show how Lucifer abandoned Hell and moved to LA to run a nightclub called *Lux* (which is shown in latest *Lucifer* television series). The rest of Lucifer's solo career takes place after these events.